# Fetch all the posts of all the users from Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a **Flutter** app. Cloud firestore database structure is given in the picture. I want to get all the posts of all the users using a **`StreamBuilder`**. How can I do that? So far I have tried this :

```
Stream<List<PostModel>> jobs() {
    return usersCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
        doc['posts'].map((docu) {
          return PostModel.fromSnapshot(docu);
        });
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

[image: Firestore Database Structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all the document in all of the subcollections called "posts" (for all users), then you probably want a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) using [collectionGroup()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore/collectionGroup.html):

```
db.collectionGroup("posts").snapshots()...
```

This will give you all documents in any collection or subcollection called "posts", no matter where it's nested.

Comment: Tried. But still getting null. "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null." "Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => JobPostModel))". Would you please look at my try once again please?

Comment: Got It. Thank You.