# How to get data from firebase sub collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get data from firebase but im a bit struggling . I have this videos collection where I saving video ids and thenevery video has documetnfield and also a sub collection called user votes . In side that im saving the user votes from the ratingbarindicator
this is how to collection looks  [image]

[image]

So what I want is every document of the user votes sub colletion and then the each rating field .
but how can I do that ?What I want is calculating that together Hope anyone can help

Comment: You're looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: Ok can you maybe give a code answer im new in flutter I dont now really how to do that

Answer (score 2):

To read the data from all (sub)collections with a given name, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('uservotes')
    .get()
    ...
```

Also see:

- [Is wildcard possible in Flutter Firestore query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329139/is-wildcard-possible-in-flutter-firestore-query/63329166#63329166)
- [Fetch all the posts of all the users from Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314055/fetch-all-the-posts-of-all-the-users-from-cloud-firestore/60314174#60314174)

Comment: thanks for mentioning it, but i think it's worth mentioning that using this compound he will get all the documents of the subcollection userVotes for every Videos documents, not for a specific video ID

Answer (score 0):

you can go through collection and document like this with firebase:

```dart
final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFiresotre.instance.collection('videos').doc([theVideoDocumentID])
  .collection('uservotes').get();

final docs = querySnapshot.docs;

for(final doc in docs) {
  final data = doc.data();
  //handle each document here
}
```

Comment: it says The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'

Comment: sorry, forgot the await, i am editing the post

Comment: The error throws in this line final docs = querySnapshot.data();There it says The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data

Comment: Have you add the await keyword before the query?

Comment: Yes sorry it says The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.

Comment: oh yes indeed, my bad, i am editing the post, data() is a method for a DocumentSnapshot not a QuerySnapshot

Comment: OK that works but how can I then calculate them together ?

Comment: brother are your there ?